# displaying php page data inside a div class

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

so I have been trying and trying, and researching and trying... XD I just can't seem to get what I want to work. :(

So I have a php page I named index2.php (just cos :) ), it has a script that gets a balance for me via rpc. On the php page will only be this figure... Looks something like

90445.68667184

Now, I want this data, on another page, index.html... I tried just putting in the php code, direct into the html page, so bypassing the need for the php page. Like so...

```
<div class="progress2">
<div class="amount">
<?php

echo '<p></p>';
$netcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://MYDATAHERE/');
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($netcoin->getbalance()); echo "\n";
echo "Received: ".$netcoin->getbalancebylabel("MYDATAHERE")."\n";
echo "</pre>"; ?>
</div>
</div>
```

And it worked! The thermometer went up! (which is the ultimate aim) (I had the include jsonRPCClient at the top in php brakets)

Only it chopped off everything after it! XD

I know there is probably a reason why, maybe it is something simple I can add to make that not happen? lol

Or I have been looking at jquery, and making ajax calls to get the php data into the div. But no success with it at all. :(

Also to note, I ultimately want 3 balances displayed on 3 seperate thermometers.

I have looked and looked on here, there are many answers and I have been trying, I just can't seem to get any to work for me. A little nudge please :)

I hope that is enough info and I am not too annoying asking such a simple thing, that has been asked before, but I just can't get my head around it.

EDIT: This bit

```
echo '<p></p>';,
```

is only there because I grabbed the code from an example and it said hello world, I tried just deleting it all but it broke, so I just deleted the hello world part XD

```
<div class="progress2">
<div class="amount">
<script ="text/javascript">
$("#amount").load("ajax/index2.php");
</script>
</div>
</div>
```

This is an exmaple of the ajax I tried... But another problem is I have 3 thermometers, you see progress2? and then amount? All 3 have amount, not amount1, amount2 etc...

This bit at the top, (I have a ticker on there too hence the cryptsyapi.php which works fine btw)

```
<?php
//require_once('blocks/bc_daemon.php');
require_once('cryptsyapi.php');
//$network_info = getinfo();
//$net_speed = getnetworkhashps();
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
?>
```

This bit I have in the div.

```
<?php
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1 ); ?>

echo '<p></p>';
$netcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://MYINFO/');
echo "<pre>\n";
print_r($netcoin->getbalance()); echo "\n";
echo "Received: ".$netcoin->getbalancebylabel("MYINFO")."\n";
echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

Is this all correct so far for displaying the errors?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and rewrite the question with less rambling and more specifics about actual problems. I've read it several times and can't really figure out what your specific issue is

Comment: Hmmm okay XD....  but I thought it was all there, I wanna call some data into a div. I mean... Not really THAT complex, The data I want is called using php, I tried to put the code above into the html page direct, as is, as per the example... But it cut off the rest of the html page... I have tried to make a seperate php page and use ajax to call it, but can't get it to work. Does that make more sense?

Comment: most servers aren't set to compile php in a `.html` file. No idea why ajax doesn't work, and you haven't provided any code for that. Also not clear why when you put everything in a `.php` file it doesn't work. So conclusion is....you need to rework teh whole question and be mroe specific

Comment: Right I see, well when I put it in the html, I did name the file .php and it did work to a degree, the thermo went up... Oh happy days, but nothing would display after it, like the footer of the page for example

Comment: And yeah I know I didn't provide any ajax example... For one it is way more complex to me than this, and non of you understand what I am saying here, can you imagine ajax? XD Two: I was hoping there was a quick fix for why the html was getting cut off.

Comment: jquery `load()` is pretty simple

Comment: To be fair though I did actually put links to the pages so you guys could see, only I don't have a domain name for it yet and this site wouldn't allow me to post the IP.

Comment: Man... If you know how maybe XD I have tried various methods, let me get some examples and pop them in the op

Comment: what does  `XD` mean?

Comment: $("#content_div").load("ajax/page_url.php"); Okay this is small I'll just put it here if I can... Oh XD is a big smile with me closing my eyes lol sorry

Comment: I in the above example I changed the content_div to amount and I changed ajax/page_url.php to ajax/index2.php... But where do I put it? How do I enable it properly?

Comment: I tried <script type="text/javascript></script> etc, I tried adding the ajax library into the header, into the div, you name it...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: Okay hmmm I need to try this again, how do I delete the entire post or does a mod have to do that, sorry guys I'm really tired to be honest, been up for days dealing with stuff like this and I'm a bit burned out

Comment: But yeah problem = PHP cuts off the page... why?

Comment: Nothing after the php code above will display

Comment: Thermo works though, as in it is accepting the data... thermo goes up to the correct amount, but why does it then not show the rest of the html

Comment: Look here is an example page, it isn't THE page I am working on, just an early version, sizing all wrong XD I don't have the needed deps installed on this server to show you it cutting off the page... http://netcoinfoundation.org/development/

Comment: But you see the second thermo, I am working on that, I put the php code into the html, name the page .php and thermo goes up, it worked! But then no thermo 3, no footer, no news, no nothing after...

Comment: Thermo 1 is there, header all before it is being displayed but absolutely nothing after, like it sees the php closing tag and says yup, that's it done

Comment: I'm hoping there is a quick fix for this problem rather than having to delve into jquery, cos I tried with no success. This must be a known issue with php surely?

Comment: turn on display errors, also check for any files named error.log in the same directory as this code.

Comment: I think I turned on display errors as per the other chaps suggestion below, but I don't see any read out :( And there is no file error.log in this directory. It is something I am making myself from a template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please put

```
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1 ); ?>
```

at the top, most likely you're not getting the rest of the page because of an error in the php which will stop the execution.

Is that part in your code as is ( with the ending comma ? )

```
echo '<p></p>';,
```

If part of the php code works, and you have content after it that does not display then you have a syntax error somewhere.

Another thing to try is comment out all the php and see if the parts of the page that are missing show.

then backtrack the end comment through the code tell the page stops displaying.

```
/*  

$badphpcod - there. -- page will work
*/


/*  
 */
$badphpcod - there. -- page won't work'




<?php
<?php ini_set('display_errors', 1 ); ?>
```

^this is not correct
try it like this.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1 );
//other code here
```

you cant do this, and expect it to work.  ( cant nest php tags )

```
<?php <?php ?> ?>



   /// -- remove this php start tag <?php
    <?php ini_set('display_errors', 1 );//---- remove this php end tag ?>

    echo '<p></p>';
    $netcoin = new jsonRPCClient('http://MYINFO/');
    echo "<pre>\n";
    print_r($netcoin->getbalance()); echo "\n";
/*echo "Received: ".$netcoin->getbalancebylabel("MYINFO")."\n";*/
    echo "</pre>"; ?>
```

you want to wind up with something like this, so you know exactly where the problem is, chances are your $netcoin is not an object or something, like a required file was not included..

I found the library you are using, do you have this in there

```
require_once 'jsonRPCClient.php';
```

for reference this is where the OP code came from
https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_%28JSON-RPC%29#PHP

you can also try this library, https://github.com/aceat64/EasyBitcoin-PHP

Answer (score -1):

first of all your question is not at all clear, read it several times but couldn't get it completely. the only thing that i get is you want some data from a url and wanted to show that data in index.html either by RPC or jquery.

Here is the easiest you can get using jquery : 
http://www.w3schools.com/JQuery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax

Comment: Okay well, I dunno why it is so unclear but guess it must be if everyone says so lol... please see above and maybe it will be clearer. I mean usually if I am not clear about what someone wants, I just ask to clarify what I am confused about.

Comment: And sorry just looked at your suggestion and it has a button, I don't want a button, just want it to load when the page does.

Comment: so if you want it to load it when page loads put it directly inside $(document).ready(function(){
//your ajax code here
});

hope it will be helpful.